# Adjust SL to Entry Price at First TP?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to create a tradingview pine script strategy that manages trades as such:

1. Every open trade will have a stop loss, and 2 take profit levels. The SL level will be at a multiple of the ATR as is already implemented. The first TP level will be at the same distance as the SL from the entry price in the profitable direction, and the second TP level will be another step above that, same distance.
2. When the price reaches the first TP level, adjust the SL to the trade's entry price and don't allow it to move back in the opposite direction from then on.
3. When the price reaches the second TP level, adjust the SL to what the first TP's level was, and start trailing it up from there, not allowing it to go the opposite direction at all from then on.
4. When a trade trips the SL level at any point, exit the trade.
5. When a signal in the opposite direction is triggered, it will close any open position and open a new one in the new direction.

Most of this I have working already, but I'm having an issue with step 2. I will post my "sort of" working, minimal code below. I have stripped it of any short conditions so we can focus on long entries/exits only, as well as implemented a simple swing strategy, which isn't important to the issue.

The problem with the code now, is I have this section commented out:

```
    ///////////////// HERE IS THE ISSUE /////////////////
    // if tp1_reached_long and not tp2_reached_long
    //     sl_level_long := math.max(initial_sl_level_long, entry_price)
    ///////////////// HERE IS THE ISSUE /////////////////
```

If I have that section commented out, the rest of the trade management works as it should, but without this section in place, I lose the ability to perform step 2. This is what the chart looks like with it commented out:

[image: workingChart]

(Notice at the blue X is where the red SL line SHOULD adjust to the order's entry price as per the requirements, but doesn't)

Then, when you uncomment that section, the chart looks like this:

[image: notWorkingChart]

(Notice how the red SL line is in the completely wrong area, like it's being set from a previous initial value many bars ago?)

Both me and ChatGPT are at a loss on how to figure this out. I'm opening it up to SO with my fingers crossed someone can figure out how to do this. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73290324/pine-scripit-moving-sl-to-previous-tp), unanswered, and different than what I'm after.

(NOTE to reproduce, copy paste this code into a strategy, and apply it to a 5-minute SPY chart to see the same results for March 2-6)

**UPDATE**
I've included the full code below with both long and short positions, as well as a screenshot to demonstrate the issue I'm having, as well as what the desired behaviour looks like. Notice how the SL adjusts to break even when the first TP is hit, then again it moves to the first TP level when the 2nd TP level is hit, and trails up from there. When price drops below SL, trade is closed. On the shorts next to it, they open/close/open/close:

[image: issueAndDesiredOutcome]

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © windowshopr

//@version=5
//============================================================================//
// STRATEGY
//============================================================================//
strategy("My strategy", shorttitle="My strategy", 
     overlay=true, 
     initial_capital=1000, 
     pyramiding=1, 
     calc_on_order_fills=true, 
     calc_on_every_tick=true, 
     backtest_fill_limits_assumption=10, 
     default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, 
     default_qty_value=100, 
     currency=currency.NONE, 
     slippage=10, 
     commission_type=strategy.commission.cash_per_contract, 
     commission_value=0.01)
//============================================================================//



//============================================================================//
// GLOBAL INPUTS
//============================================================================//
// Strategy Specific Inputs
input_consecutive_contrarian_candles_count = input.int(
     title = "Consecutive candles count minimum", 
     minval = 0, 
     defval = 18, 
     group = 'Strategy',
     tooltip = 'How many consecutive candles have to happen in a row before starting to look for swing entry')

input_leeway_candles_count = input.int(
     title = "Allow X opposite candles", 
     minval = 0, 
     defval = 2, 
     group = 'Strategy',
     tooltip = 'Allow for X many candles in opposite direction of total count to still be valid')

// Trading Session Inputs
input_trading_hours = input.bool(
     title = "Use Trading Session/Time?", 
     defval = true, 
     group = 'Time/Session',
     tooltip = 'Use trading session?')

input_start_trading_hour = input.int(
     title = "Begin trading hour", 
     minval = 0, 
     defval = 9, 
     maxval = 23,
     group = 'Time/Session',
     tooltip = 'The hour to begin trading at if Use Trading Hours is True')

input_start_trading_minute = input.int(
     title = "Begin trading minute", 
     minval = 0, 
     defval = 30, 
     maxval = 59,
     group = 'Time/Session',
     tooltip = 'The minute to begin trading at if Use Trading Hours is True')

input_end_trading_hour = input.int(
     title = "End trading hour", 
     minval = 0, 
     defval = 16, 
     maxval = 23,
     group = 'Time/Session',
     tooltip = 'The hour to end trading at if Use Trading Hours is True')

input_end_trading_minute = input.int(
     title = "End trading minute", 
     minval = 0, 
     defval = 00, 
     maxval = 59,
     group = 'Time/Session',
     tooltip = 'The minute to end trading at if Use Trading Hours is True')

is_trading_session = not input_trading_hours or 
     (input_trading_hours and 
     ((hour > input_start_trading_hour or (hour == input_start_trading_hour and minute >= input_start_trading_minute)) and
     (hour < input_end_trading_hour or (hour == input_end_trading_hour and minute <= input_end_trading_minute))
     )) ? true : false


// General TP/SL Inputs
input_atr_length = input.int(
     title = 'ATR Length', 
     minval = 1, 
     defval = 480, 
     group = 'General SL',
     tooltip = 'How many previous candles to use for the ATR calculation.')

input_atr_mult = input.float(
     title = 'ATR Mult (Long & Short)', 
     minval = 0.1, 
     step = 0.1, 
     defval = 10.0, 
     tooltip = 'Take Profit ATR Multiplier', 
     group = 'General SL')
//============================================================================//


//============================================================================//
// STRATEGY LOGIC
//============================================================================//
// Define your strategy's logic below, ending with long_condition and 
// short_condition booleans
var int current_consecutive_up_candles_count = 0
var int current_consecutive_down_candles_count = 0
var int current_up_leeway_candles_count = 0
var int current_down_leeway_candles_count = 0

var bool longTradeAllowed = false
var bool shortTradeAllowed = false

if close[1] > open[1]
    current_consecutive_up_candles_count += 1
    current_up_leeway_candles_count += 1
else if close[1] < open[1]
    current_consecutive_down_candles_count += 1
    current_down_leeway_candles_count += 1

if current_up_leeway_candles_count >= input_leeway_candles_count
    current_consecutive_down_candles_count := 0
    current_down_leeway_candles_count := 0
    current_up_leeway_candles_count := 0
else if current_down_leeway_candles_count >= input_leeway_candles_count
    current_consecutive_up_candles_count := 0
    current_down_leeway_candles_count := 0
    current_up_leeway_candles_count := 0

if current_consecutive_up_candles_count + current_down_leeway_candles_count >= input_consecutive_contrarian_candles_count
    shortTradeAllowed := true
else
    shortTradeAllowed := false
if current_consecutive_down_candles_count + current_up_leeway_candles_count >= input_consecutive_contrarian_candles_count
    longTradeAllowed := true
else
    longTradeAllowed := false

// Returns here
long_condition = ta.crossover(high, high[1]) and longTradeAllowed 
short_condition = ta.crossunder(low, low[1]) and shortTradeAllowed
//============================================================================//


//============================================================================//
// TRADE MANAGEMENT
//============================================================================//
// Potential entry for positions
bool potential_open_long_position = long_condition
bool potential_open_short_position = short_condition

// Check if we're currently active in a position
bool longIsActive = strategy.position_size > 0
bool shortIsActive = strategy.position_size < 0

// the open signals when not already into a position
bool validOpenLongPosition = potential_open_long_position and is_trading_session
bool validOpenShortPosition = potential_open_short_position and is_trading_session

// Check for order close conditions
bool closeLongPosition = (potential_open_short_position or not is_trading_session) and longIsActive
bool closeShortPosition = (potential_open_long_position or not is_trading_session) and shortIsActive
//============================================================================//

// ATR Calculation
float atr = ta.atr(input_atr_length)

entry_price = longIsActive or shortIsActive ? strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1) : na

// Stop Loss and Take Profit levels
float sl_distance = atr * input_atr_mult
float tp1_distance = sl_distance
float tp2_distance = sl_distance * 2

float sl_level_long = na
float tp1_level_long = na
float tp2_level_long = na
var float initial_sl_level_long = na

float sl_level_short = na
float tp1_level_short = na
float tp2_level_short = na
var float initial_sl_level_short = na



// Manage Long Positions
var bool tp1_reached_long = false
var bool tp2_reached_long = false
if longIsActive

    sl_level_long := entry_price - sl_distance
    initial_sl_level_long := na( initial_sl_level_long[1] ) ? sl_level_long : initial_sl_level_long[1]
    tp1_level_long := entry_price + tp1_distance
    tp2_level_long := entry_price + tp2_distance

    // Exit the position when the low crosses below the current SL level
    if low < sl_level_long[1]
        strategy.close("Long Entry")

    // Check if high crosses above TP1 and TP2
    if high >= tp1_level_long and not tp1_reached_long
        tp1_reached_long := true

    if high >= tp2_level_long and not tp2_reached_long
        tp2_reached_long := true

    if tp1_reached_long and not tp2_reached_long
        sl_level_long := math.max(initial_sl_level_long, entry_price)
        strategy.exit("Long Entry", stop=sl_level_long)

    if tp2_reached_long
        sl_level_long := math.max(sl_level_long[1], tp1_level_long, high - sl_distance)

if validOpenLongPosition
    strategy.entry("Long Entry", strategy.long)

// Manage Short Positions
var bool tp1_reached_short = false
var bool tp2_reached_short = false
if shortIsActive

    sl_level_short := entry_price + sl_distance
    initial_sl_level_short := na( initial_sl_level_short[1] ) ? sl_level_short : initial_sl_level_short[1]
    tp1_level_short := entry_price - tp1_distance
    tp2_level_short := entry_price - tp2_distance

    // Exit the position when the high crosses above the current SL level
    if high > sl_level_short[1]
        strategy.close("Short Entry")

    // Check if low crosses below TP1 and TP2
    if low <= tp1_level_short and not tp1_reached_short
        tp1_reached_short := true

    if low <= tp2_level_short and not tp2_reached_short
        tp2_reached_short := true

    if tp1_reached_short and not tp2_reached_short
        sl_level_short := math.min(initial_sl_level_short, entry_price)
        strategy.exit("Short Entry", stop=sl_level_short)

    if tp2_reached_short
        sl_level_short := math.min(sl_level_short[1], tp1_level_short, low + sl_distance)

if validOpenShortPosition
    strategy.entry("Short Entry", strategy.short)

// SL Plots
plot(series = sl_level_long, title = 'Long Trail Stop', color = color.new(#e25141, 0), linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr, offset = 1)
plot(series = sl_level_short, title = 'Short Trail Stop', color = color.new(#e25141, 0), linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr, offset = 1)

// TP 1 Plots
plot(series = tp1_level_long, title = 'Long TP 1', color = color.new(#61e241, 0), linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr, offset = 1)
plot(series = tp1_level_short, title = 'Short TP 1', color = color.new(#61e241, 0), linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr, offset = 1)

// TP 2 Plots
plot(series = tp2_level_long, title = 'Long TP 2', color = color.new(#4cff20, 0), linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr, offset = 1)
plot(series = tp2_level_short, title = 'Short TP 2', color = color.new(#4cff20, 0), linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr, offset = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main error in your script is that you ask for a 480 lentgh atr, which produce a NaN (Not a Number) response, and then all your calculation from the atr became NaN.

I change the value by default to 20 (for testing purpose) and correct several things in your script, in particular, the use of strategy.exit to create and update your stop loss.

Here is the result :

```
//@version=5
//============================================================================//
// STRATEGY
//============================================================================//
strategy("My strategy", shorttitle="My strategy", 
     overlay=true, 
     initial_capital=1000, 
     pyramiding=1, 
     calc_on_order_fills=true, 
     calc_on_every_tick=true, 
     backtest_fill_limits_assumption=10, 
     default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, 
     default_qty_value=100, 
     currency=currency.NONE, 
     slippage=10, 
     commission_type=strategy.commission.cash_per_contract, 
     commission_value=0.01,
     max_labels_count=500)
//============================================================================//



//============================================================================//
// GLOBAL INPUTS
//============================================================================//
// Strategy Specific Inputs
input_consecutive_contrarian_candles_count = input.int(
     title = "Consecutive candles count minimum", 
     minval = 0, 
     defval = 18, 
     group = 'Strategy',
     tooltip = 'How many consecutive candles have to happen in a row before starting to look for swing entry')

input_leeway_candles_count = input.int(
     title = "Allow X opposite candles", 
     minval = 0, 
     defval = 2, 
     group = 'Strategy',
     tooltip = 'Allow for X many candles in opposite direction of total count to still be valid')

// Trading Session Inputs
input_trading_hours = input.bool(
     title = "Use Trading Session/Time?", 
     defval = true, 
     group = 'Time/Session',
     tooltip = 'Use trading session?')

input_start_trading_hour = input.int(
     title = "Begin trading hour", 
     minval = 0, 
     defval = 9, 
     maxval = 23,
     group = 'Time/Session',
     tooltip = 'The hour to begin trading at if Use Trading Hours is True')

input_start_trading_minute = input.int(
     title = "Begin trading minute", 
     minval = 0, 
     defval = 30, 
     maxval = 59,
     group = 'Time/Session',
     tooltip = 'The minute to begin trading at if Use Trading Hours is True')

input_end_trading_hour = input.int(
     title = "End trading hour", 
     minval = 0, 
     defval = 16, 
     maxval = 23,
     group = 'Time/Session',
     tooltip = 'The hour to end trading at if Use Trading Hours is True')

input_end_trading_minute = input.int(
     title = "End trading minute", 
     minval = 0, 
     defval = 00, 
     maxval = 59,
     group = 'Time/Session',
     tooltip = 'The minute to end trading at if Use Trading Hours is True')

is_trading_session = not input_trading_hours or 
     (input_trading_hours and 
     ((hour > input_start_trading_hour or (hour == input_start_trading_hour and minute >= input_start_trading_minute)) and
     (hour < input_end_trading_hour or (hour == input_end_trading_hour and minute <= input_end_trading_minute))
     )) ? true : false


// General TP/SL Inputs
input_atr_length = input.int(20, title = 'ATR Length', minval = 1, group = 'General SL',tooltip = 'How many previous candles to use for the ATR calculation.')

input_atr_mult = input.float(10, 'ATR Mult (Long & Short)', minval = 0.1, step = 0.1, tooltip = 'Take Profit ATR Multiplier', group = 'General SL')
//============================================================================//


//============================================================================//
// STRATEGY LOGIC
//============================================================================//
// Define your strategy's logic below, ending with long_condition and 
// short_condition booleans
var int current_consecutive_up_candles_count = 0
var int current_up_leeway_candles_count = 0
var int current_down_leeway_candles_count = 0
var int current_consecutive_down_candles_count = 0

var bool longTradeAllowed = false

if close[1] > open[1]
    current_consecutive_up_candles_count += 1
    current_up_leeway_candles_count += 1

if current_down_leeway_candles_count >= input_leeway_candles_count
    current_consecutive_up_candles_count := 0
    current_down_leeway_candles_count := 0
    current_up_leeway_candles_count := 0

if current_consecutive_down_candles_count + current_up_leeway_candles_count >= input_consecutive_contrarian_candles_count
    longTradeAllowed := true
else
    longTradeAllowed := false

// Returns here
long_condition = ta.crossover(high, high[1]) and longTradeAllowed 
//============================================================================//


//============================================================================//
// TRADE MANAGEMENT
//============================================================================//
// Potential entry for positions
bool potential_open_long_position = long_condition

// the open signals when not already into a position
bool validOpenLongPosition = potential_open_long_position and is_trading_session

// Check for order close conditions
bool closeLongPosition = not is_trading_session and strategy.opentrades > 0
//============================================================================//

// ATR Calculation
float Atr = ta.atr(input_atr_length)

var float entry_price = close //strategy.opentrades > 0 ? strategy.position_avg_price : na

// Stop Loss and Take Profit levels
float sl_distance = Atr * input_atr_mult
float tp1_distance = sl_distance
float tp2_distance = sl_distance * 2

var float sl_level_long = na
var float tp1_level_long = na
var float tp2_level_long = na
var float initial_sl_level_long = na

// Manage Long Positions
var bool tp1_reached_long = false
var bool tp2_reached_long = false
if strategy.opentrades > 0
    //sl_level_long := entry_price - sl_distance
    initial_sl_level_long := na( initial_sl_level_long[1] ) ? sl_level_long : initial_sl_level_long[1]
    //tp1_level_long := entry_price + tp1_distance
    //tp2_level_long := entry_price + tp2_distance

    // Exit the position when the low crosses below the current SL level
    if low < sl_level_long
        strategy.close("Long Entry")

    // Check if high crosses above TP1 and TP2
    if high >= tp1_level_long and not tp1_reached_long
        tp1_reached_long := true
        label.new(bar_index, close, "tp1_reached_long")

    if high >= tp2_level_long and not tp2_reached_long
        tp2_reached_long := true
        label.new(bar_index, close, "tp2_reached_long")

    ///////////////// HERE IS THE ISSUE /////////////////
    if tp1_reached_long and not tp2_reached_long
        sl_level_long := math.max(initial_sl_level_long, entry_price)
        strategy.exit("SL", from_entry = "Long Entry", stop = sl_level_long)

    ///////////////// HERE IS THE ISSUE /////////////////

    if tp2_reached_long and false
        sl_level_long := math.max(sl_level_long[1], tp1_level_long, high - sl_distance)
        label.new(bar_index, close, "tp2_reached_long true")

if validOpenLongPosition and strategy.opentrades == 0
    strategy.cancel_all()
    strategy.entry("Long Entry", strategy.long)
    entry_price := close
    tp1_level_long := close + tp1_distance
    tp2_level_long := close + tp2_distance
    sl_level_long := close - sl_distance
    label.new(bar_index, close, str.tostring(Atr))
    strategy.exit("SL", from_entry = "Long Entry", stop = sl_level_long)

// SL Plots
plot(series = sl_level_long, title = 'Long Trail Stop', color = strategy.opentrades > 0 ? color.new(#e25141, 0) : na, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr, offset = 1)

// TP 1 Plots
plot(series = tp1_level_long, title = 'Long TP 1', color = strategy.opentrades > 0 ? color.new(#61e241, 0) : na, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr, offset = 1)

// TP 2 Plots
plot(series = tp2_level_long, title = 'Long TP 2', color = strategy.opentrades > 0 ? color.new(#4cff20, 0) : na, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr, offset = 1)
```

Comment: @windowshopr In your code, as longIsActive, initial_sl_level_long is updated. So the SL of the strategy.exit update also. You should record initial_sl_level_long and entry_price and not update it once th trade is opened. This way you will have your correct SL

Comment: @windowshopr if I copy your code as is, it generate a lot of error. Please edit your question and paste the entire code you are using.

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't work either because the SL's don't move at all now? I've updated the code again above and provided an UPDATE section that has a screenshot of what I want, and what the code issue is. Hopefully that helps to understand.

Comment: @windowshopr your update code doesn't produce any trade on SPY 5m ???

Comment: I've just confirmed that it does open trades as is, as that is where I captured the updated screenshot from. Ensure you have extended trading hours enabled on the chart? Not sure what else to recommend.

Comment: @windowshopr your issue in your question was : ///////////////// HERE IS THE ISSUE /////////////////
    // if tp1_reached_long and not tp2_reached_long
    //     sl_level_long := math.max(initial_sl_level_long, entry_price)

Comment: yes I know that haha that's why I marked it as here is the issue. I would invite you to look at the third updated screenshot to see both the desired and undesired behaviour that the code is doing. Please post an updated code if you have a fix.

Answer (score 0):

This code achieves what I need. The TP levels aren't static, however I actually don't mind that as if price range is getting smaller, it could mean a reversal is coming so the TP levels tighten up. The SL remains static, and adjusts as the 2 TP levels are hit, and trails accordingly. Inspiration was taken from here:

[tradingViewLinkToSimilarCode](https://www.tradingview.com/script/jjhUHcje-Stepped-trailing-strategy-example/)

```
if validOpenLongPosition
    strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long)
else if validOpenShortPosition
    strategy.entry("Enter Short", strategy.short)

// Calculate ATR value in ticks
atr_value_in_ticks = ta.atr(input_atr_length) * input_atr_mult / syminfo.mintick

// Calculate the SL and TP levels in ticks
sl = atr_value_in_ticks
tp1 = atr_value_in_ticks
tp2 = atr_value_in_ticks * 2

curProfitInPts() =>
    if longIsActive
        (high - strategy.position_avg_price) / syminfo.mintick
    else if shortIsActive
        (strategy.position_avg_price - low) / syminfo.mintick
    else
        0
        
calcStopLossPrice(OffsetTicks) =>
    if longIsActive
        strategy.position_avg_price - OffsetTicks * syminfo.mintick
    else if shortIsActive
        strategy.position_avg_price + OffsetTicks * syminfo.mintick
    else
        na
        
calcProfitTrgtPrice(OffsetTicks) =>
    calcStopLossPrice(-OffsetTicks)

getCurrentStage() =>
    var int stage = 0
    if strategy.position_size == 0
        stage := 0
    if stage == 0 and strategy.position_size != 0
        stage := 1
    else if stage == 1 and curProfitInPts() >= tp1
        stage := 2
    else if stage == 2 and curProfitInPts() >= tp2
        stage := 3
    stage

float stopLevel = na
float trailOffsetLevel = na
var float previousStopLevel = na

curStage = getCurrentStage()

// Stage 1 = Open position, not over first TP level
if curStage == 1
    stopLevel := na(stopLevel[1]) ? calcStopLossPrice(sl) : stopLevel[1]
    strategy.exit("x", stop = stopLevel, comment = "sl")
// Stage 2 = Open position, reached TP1 level, not yet reached TP2 level (SL adjusts to entry price)
else if curStage == 2
    stopLevel := calcStopLossPrice(0)
    strategy.exit("x", stop = stopLevel, comment = "breakeven")
// Stage 3 = Open position, price surpassed TP2 level, SL should be adjusted to math.max(TP1 level, (current high - atr_value_in_ticks), (current high - atr_value_in_ticks)[1])
else if curStage == 3
    if longIsActive
        stopLevel := math.max(calcStopLossPrice(tp1), high - atr_value_in_ticks * syminfo.mintick, previousStopLevel[1])
    else if shortIsActive
        stopLevel := math.min(calcStopLossPrice(-tp1), low + atr_value_in_ticks * syminfo.mintick, previousStopLevel[1])
    strategy.exit("x", stop = stopLevel, comment = "trailing SL")
else
    strategy.cancel("x")

// Update previousStopLevel variable
previousStopLevel := stopLevel

// plot the SL, TP1, and TP2 levels for visual verification
plot(stopLevel, style = plot.style_linebr, color = color.red)
plot(calcProfitTrgtPrice(tp1), style = plot.style_linebr, color = color.green)
plot(calcProfitTrgtPrice(tp2), style = plot.style_linebr, color = color.rgb(0, 250, 83))
```